# How hard would it be for people to decrypt this encrypting code I created?

Tags: java, encryption

I created an encryption program and I am wondering how hard it would be for a cracker to decrypt the output from this program?

My computer is having trouble pasting the code here so [here is a link where you can download it.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3C5Fcj-ffTdLUtSM0JXUW1EcjA/view?usp=sharing)

This encryption program works by taking the ASCII value of each character, square-rooting it, and then multiplying the result by 8.

Then, it replaces the space between each character's double with one of 500 strings which are formatted like this: (Random amount of whitespace)(Random 5-digit integer)(Random amount of whitespace).

And then finally, it replaces the decimal point with one of 500 similarly-formatted strings.

The program just does everything in reverse to decrypt the encrypted files.

What do you guys think? Thanks

Comment: Is this just for an academic exercise, or are you thinking about actually using this for real-world purposes?

Comment: @chrylis this was just for fun and to see if I could do it as I am new to Java. I wouldn't post it on here otherwise haha :)

Comment: If you seriously care about security, read about Java AES encryption

Comment: Okay, just making sure that you weren't actually intending this to provide real security. I don't think that Stack Overflow is the place to ask this question, because it's more about theoretical cryptography. I suggest the Crypto SE site: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptanalysis

Comment: @chrylis Okay thanks will do :)

Comment: It also looks to me like it's possible that you can't decrypt everything correctly. for one becausing reversing sqrt may not be accurate since floating point numbers have finite precision and secondly because you assume that you can identify which parts are random space filler and which aren't - I guess it's possible that the encrypted ascii matches such a sequence and you replace the wrong thing.

Comment: @zapl Do you mean as in two of the strings happening to be next to each other and then being mistaken for the wrong string by the program during decryption?

Answer (score 2):

Since there is no secret part of that algorithm, the "cracker" would just write a decryption algorithm you described and get the original message. It is not the algorithm complexity that makes the encryption strong. For the currently used encryption algorithms the algorithm itself is publicly available. It is a "secret" - a decryption key known only to the recipient of the encrypted message -  that makes it strong. Start by looking at the article on [public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography).

I assume this is just for research/fun, but a word of advice: never try to implement your own encryption scheme, use one of the existing and proven algorithms.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But how hard would it be for them to create such an algorithm, just out of curiosity.

Comment: Since you just described it - not hard at all ;) But honestly, much harder algorithms have been cracked (usually under certain conditions). Just search for "cracked cryptography algorithms". Also, [this is an interesting thread](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32779).

Comment: Haha, I have suddenly been intrigued into the world of cryptography now. Well see you in a few months outside world, I have some reading to do. So if I'm correct, encryption techniques rely on the limits of our knowledge of mathematics. If this premise is true, then how could we possible decrypt them?